# How to retireve 10 nodes from a XML file?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm reading data from a xml file.
I load the file ok, but now I'm struggling to read just the first 10 nodes.
Any idea on how to to do this?

```
 doc = FlexiUtils.LoadXMLFile(Resources.Resources.MockProductDetailsFile + 
                productName + Resources.Resources.DetailsExtension);

            XmlNodeList e = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Row");


<Response>
  <Rows>
    <Row>
      <Column Name="Ticker"><![CDATA[]]></Column>
      <Column Name="SecurityName"><![CDATA[POLAND 4 1/2 01/18/22]]></Column>
      <Column Name="Currency"><![CDATA[EUR]]></Column>
      <Column Name="Sector"><![CDATA[GOVERNMENT]]></Column>
    </Row>
...
  </Rows>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var nodes = e.OfType<XmlNode>().Take(10);
```